What do I need to improve on the 645648 ID question so that I have a better chance of getting an answer?
What do I need to improve on this question Interpretation of this learning rate finder plot$^\dagger$ to have a better chance of getting an answer?
--
$\dagger$ deleted by the author

It’s not clear from the question what part you’re unclear on. Assuming the software implements the paper faithfully , then reading the paper describes how to arrive at the result. So, are you really asking what the Smith paper does? Or something else?

@Sycorax It follow ideas from the paper, but I want an interpretation of my specific plot.

"The statistic is small for reasons that are idiosyncratic to the data."

I did not understand what you said.

One way to make your question more approachable is to make it unnecessary to follow two links that you added before people are able to understand your question. (in addition, links can lead to linkrot* and questions and answers should work ideally without them)
Make at least a concise description such that the point of your question is clear.
Currently people see mostly an unexplained (imo weird and vague) graph

I might be capable to answer your question, but I have no idea what that graph means and why it does what it does. I also don't know what you are doing. What loss, what training, what problem, some introduction (not verbose, but just concise) can be useful.

If you explain your graph a bit more then you get more people interested in your question and in addition the mere explaining might help yourself to understand the problem better.

*See what I did there with the added link to this answer? It is a demonstration of how links can be used. In this case it is just a helpful link that people can use to get more information, but it is not essential. And if ever the Wikipedia doesn't exist anymore, the term 'linkrot' tells enough and people can look it up in another encyclopedia.
